# Get foreign key related JSON objects in Django template

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates

So I currently have an API response that encodes a many-to-one relationship both ways, where the one object (called Sagas) has a set of the many objects (called Arcs) relating to it:

```json
//1 Saga contains many arcs in this way:

//GET Saga
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "arc_set": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6
        ],
        "name": "East Blue",
        "description": "The East Blue Saga is the introductory saga of the series...",
        "startChapter": 1,
        "endChapter": 100
    },
]

//GET Arc
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Orange Town",
        "description": "Luffy and his first crew member Zoro arrive at Orange Town where....",
        "startChapter": 8,
        "endChapter": 21,
        "saga": 1
    },
]
```

basically I want to be able to go through the arc_set in my django template and grab the related arcs with the matching ids. It seems simple I'm just not too familiar with the django template syntax needed

Currently all I've been working on is code to loop through the arc_set array and get the id values but I can't even get that to work, never mind getting the related Arc object:

```html
{% for saga in sagas|dictsort:'id' %}
 {% for arc_key, arc_id in saga.arc_set.items|dictsort:'id' %}
```

but I've been unable to iterate through the arc_set data, even though doing `<p> {{saga.arc_set}} </p>` displays an array of all the values

Comment: You need to implement a custom filter to access the value in a dict. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working by just looping through all arcs in the arc_set and then looping through all the arcs and checking if the two were equal, seems like a lot of unnecessary nested looping but it's the only way I could get it working at the moment.

```
        {% for saga in sagas|dictsort:'order' %}
            <h1>{{saga.name}}</h1>
            {% for arc_id in saga.arc_set %}
                {% for arc in arcs|dictsort:'order'  %}
                    {% if arc.id == arc_id %}
                        <h2>{{ arc.name }} Arc</h2>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I would change API to return list of arc items insted of list of ids